# Azure Blob Storage and NestJs: The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server

Tags: nestjs, azure-blob-storage

**Issue**
When sending request to create blob files, I got this error message:

`The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.`

**Background**

I have Azure Blob Storage set up and have the following data:

- Account name
- Access key
- Connection string
- Connection URL
- Container. Example: Container name: "TestContainer"

The above was also used to configure Azure Blob Storage connection in my NestJS project.

I want to create files inside the "TestContainer".

Currently, I'm using ContainerClient from @azure/storage-blob to create blob files.
Here is the code

```
import { ContainerClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

@Injectable()
export class BlobStorageService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('CONTAINER_CLIENT') private readonly containerClient: ContainerClient
  ) {}

  async create(key: string, message: any) {
    const content = JSON.stringify(message);
    try {
      const blobName = key;
      const appendBlobClient = this.containerClient.getAppendBlobClient(blobName);
      await appendBlobClient.createIfNotExists();

      await appendBlobClient.appendBlock(content, content.length);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
}
```

Please help if you have experienced this before.
Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and include how you are constructing `ContainerClient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.

The above error occurs either you are passing **`Invalid URI`** or **`incorrect URI`**.

As a workaround to upload files to azure container.I tried in my environment with **`blobserviceclient`** and **`Blockblobclient`** using following [Document.](https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2021/03/nestjs-api-file-operations-using-azure-blob-storage.html#:%7E:text=In%20this%20article,%20we%20are%20going%20to%20use,massive%20amount%20of%20file%20data%20as%20unstructured%20data.) by Naveen.

**Code:**

```
import { BlobServiceClient, BlockBlobClient } from  '@azure/storage-blob';
import { Injectable } from  '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export  class  AppService {
azureConnection = "< Connection string >";
containerName = "test";

getBlobClient(imageName:string):BlockBlobClient{
const  blobClientService = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(this.azureConnection);
const  containerClient = blobClientService.getContainerClient(this.containerName);
const  blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(imageName);
return  blobClient;
}

async  upload(file:Express.Multer.File){
const  blobClient = this.getBlobClient(file.originalname);
await  blobClient.uploadData(file.buffer);
}
}
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Postman:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[How to Upload Files to Azure using NestJS and typeORM with MySQL (freecodecamp.org)](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/upload-files-to-azure-using-nestjs-and-typeorm-with-mysql/) by Destiny Erhabor.